# Python AttributeError: Class Inheritance From a Parent Function

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributeerror

I am getting an AttributeError when I am trying to inherit an attribute from parent's class function. Does this mean that I can't inherit it directly from parent's function? This is the output:

**AttributeError: 'Two' object has no attribute 'name'**

and this is the code itself:

This is the code:

```
class One:
def ready(self):
    self.name = 'John'

class Two(One):
def __init__(self):
    print(self.name)

two = Two()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an instance of the class One the attribute name is only set when `self.ready()` is called. When you try to print it in `Two.__init__` it is not added yet and therefore raises an error. So you would need to use something like:

```py
class One:
  def ready(self):
    self.name = 'John'

class Two(One):
  def __init__(self):
    self.ready()
    print(self.name)

two = Two()
```

Comment: Thanks. What instead of def ready(self) I had __init__(self) in place?

Comment: `__init__` of the parent class is not called by default so you would have to call `super().__init__()`

Answer (score -1):

You're getting an attribute error because you're not defining any self.name in class Two. Even though, two is inheriting from One the class instances are different. You could instead try

```
   class Two(One):
     def __init__(self):
         One.ready(self)
         print(self.name)
```

Try searching what is self, inheritance and constructors in python if you want to get a better idea.

Comment: You really should use `self.ready`, I didn't downvote, btw, but I think people will not like that